# How to express this logical constraint for an ILP?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization, logical-constraints

I am trying to write an ILP for a problem but I have this logical constraint and I'm stuck.

In my model I have:

two binary variables: $x$ and $y$

One Integer variable: $z$

The logical constraint I am trying to write is:

if $x = 1$ and $y = 1$ then $z \le Mx$, else $z = 0$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, I think I was assuming $z \ge 0$.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is correct but also $z$ has an upper bound Big-M , so $0 \leq z \leq M$ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You always want $$z \ge 0 \tag1$$
You want $x = 0 \implies z \le 0$:  $$z \le M x \tag2$$  Similarly, you want $y = 0 \implies z \le 0$: $$z \le M y \tag3$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do yo think expressing it like this would work : $ z \leq 
 M (x + y - 1) $ ?

Comment: No. Consider the $(x,y)=(0,0)$ case.

Comment: Hello again , regarding the constraint that I have asked about in my previous question, I have a slight modification. I want to write the following constraint : let z be an integer variable, and t a binary variable, and a big-M. z is $0\leq z \leq M$.  the logical constraint is as following : if $ z \leq M$ and $z > 0 \Rightarrow t = 1 $ ; and if $ z = 0  \Rightarrow t = 0$. Is this $ z \leq M t $ sufficient? the t and z variables are not in my objective function but , variable t is connected to another variable in the objective function? Thank you very much, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please start a new post for this question.